# How to test dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have project to do, but as I am completely beginner in Python I'll need some help. Here is what is the goal:
I have a dictionary, more then 10000 pairs (employee and ID). Data have to be checked before I insert in dictionary:

```
people = {'Ingrid Hale': 219686, 'Clarence Spa^r#acio': 212438, 'Isabelle Fisher': 8767, 'Tammy Martinez': , 'Shana Kendall-Richard': 688078 }
```

Data have to be tested in pairs.
- Employee have to have first name and last name without any special characters and numbers
-ID have to contain only numbers and only 6 digits, it cannot be empty, it have to be unique and cannot be repeatable

I started with counting keys and values, display it in pairs and than I stopped...any advice?

Thanks!

Comment: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: Hi Branko is all your data is already in a dictionary ?

Comment: You don't have a list, you have a dictionary.

Comment: Hi, my bad description it is dict, and data are not in dictionary. I have to check them all before I write it in..

Comment: Maybe you must start with regular expressions with [re](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html) module to check the conditions and store the ids to check if each new already exists in some container while you iterate through the dict.

Comment: It is astounding how many helpful answers and comments such a poorly researched question can receive. Personally I received a question ban for far less, but I digress. At least now he knows what a dictionary is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. there is an error in your dictionary, a key can't have null value ('Tammy Martinez':);

you can try this code:

```
people = {'Ingrid Hale': 219686, 'Clarence Spa^r#acio': 212438, 'Isabelle Fisher': 8767 , 'Shana Kendall-Richard': 688078 }
symbol="~`!@#$%^&*()_-+={}[]:>;',</?*-+"
numbers="0123456789"
for x in people.keys():
    for t in x:
        if t in symbol or t in numbers:
            print (x)
            break
for x in people.keys():
    value=str(people[x])
    for h in value:
        if h not in numbers:
            print (value)
            break
```

Comment: I have to examine in dictionary and remove all "unpair" values, for instance as it is not valid pair.

Comment: @BrankoĐurkić did u manage how to delete, once that you know which one are bad you need just do it: "del dictinaty_name[key_name]" or "dictinaty_name.pop(key_name)"

Answer (score 1):

Without being able to see what you've done it's hard to give a concrete answer, but some useful snippets you can use are:

To check if you have a first and last name separated by a space you can split it on spaces and check the length: `len(emp_name.split()) == 2`.
You can check if names are only characters using `str.isalpha(emp_firstname)`

To check if your IDs are numeric you can use `str.isnumeric(emp_id)` and to check if they are of length 6 you can use `len(emp_id) == 6`

Use these and post what you come up with.

Comment: names = people.keys()
em_id = people.values()
if len(people.values()) == 6:  # check ID are length 6
    print "Display IDs shorter than 6 digits: ", em_id ... I do not get any results @Tom Sitter

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over dictionary check if employee name is alpha or not. You can check id uniqueness with set.If id is already in set so you don't have to deal with.

```
employee_id_set = set()
desired_dict = {}
for name in people:
    employee_name = name
    employee_id  = people[name]
    if employee_name.alpha():
        if employee_id not in employee_id_set:
            employee_id_set(employee_id)
            desired_dict[employee_id ] =employee_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did so far

```
# Display all pairs (employee, ID)
pairs = dict.items(people)
print "Display pairs - (employee, id): ", pairs, "\n"

# Display number of employees
print "Number of keys: ", len(people.keys())

# Display number of ID's
print "Number of values: ", len(people.values()), "\n"

names = []
em_id = []

for name, id in people.items():

emptyName = 0
emptyID = 0

if len(str(id)) != 6:
    print "Display IDs which do not have exactly 6 digits: ", id, "\n"

if ' ' not in str(name):
    print "Employees with no space in name: ", name, "\n"

if str(id) in em_id:
    uniqueId = em_id.index(str(id))
    print "Listed IDs are not unique: ", id, "\n"
    em_id.append(str(id))
else:
    em_id.append(str(id))

if '' == str(id):
    print "Display employee without ID: ", name

if str(id) == id:
    print "Not correct ID for employee: ", name

if set('[~!@#$%^&*()_-{}":;-0123456789\']+$').intersection(name):
    print "Not correct names: ", name
```

I have to examine 1 more condition in which one I stop as I lost a little bit: 
- Employees with 3 words in name and print those employees

Answer (score 0):

```
people = {'Ingrid Hale': 219686, 'Clarence Sparacio': 212438, 'Isabelle     
Fisher': 830767, 'Tammy Martinez': 98d637, 'Shana-Kendall Josh': '', 'Esther 
Zeck Martin': 9069, 

# Display number of employees
print "Number of keys: ", len(people.keys())

# Display number of ID's
print "Number of values: ", len(people.values()), "\n"

names = []
em_id = []

for name, id in people.items():

emptyName = 0
emptyID = 0

if len(str(id)) != 6:
    print "Display IDs which do not have exactly 6 digits: ", id, "\n"

elif ' ' not in str(name):
    print "Employees with no space in name: ", name, "\n"

elif str(id) in em_id:
    print "Listed IDs are not unique: ", id, "\n"
    em_id.append(str(id))
else:
    em_id.append(str(id))

if '' == str(id):
    print "Display employee without ID: ", name

elif str(id) == id:
    print "Not correct ID for employee: ", name

elif set('[~!@#$%^&*()_-{}":;-0123456789\']+$').intersection(name):
    print "Not correct names: ", name, "\n"

elif len(name.split()) == 3:
    print "Employee with 3 words: ", name

print datetime.now() - startTime, "\n"
print "THE END"
```

Thanks for help, here is final code.